# Inserting a "pointer" cursor which pointing to left and right or back and forth using Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking the "pointer" cursor which pointing left and right instead of up. i need to show the images onclick of that left/right cursor. On mouse move of the certain space in left and right side the cursor will display. Any one can you please help to solve this using jquery or javascript.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

There are only so many cursors by default. Here is a helpful list and instructions on how to use them.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

`col-resize` might be what you're looking for. If not, you'll have to make your own. Here's some instruction on how to do that.

http://davidwalsh.name/css-custom-cursor

Essentially, you'll create your cursor as an `ico` file, give it a backup cursor style in case the browse can't render your custom cursor, and then put this in your css.

```
body {
    cursor: url('some-cursor.ico'), default;
}
```